# Python - How to join elements in a list that are separated by a certain value

Tags: python, list, iteration

Suppose I have a list that looks like this:

```
['1', '+', '2', '+', '3', 'C', '4', 'C', '5', '-', '6', '+', '7', 'C', '8']
```

I want to modify it in such a way that all elements separated by a `'C'` are concatenated together. The result should look like this:

```
['1', '+', '2', '+', '345', '-', '6', '+', '78']
```

I've been trying to do this iterably, but the problem is whenever I delete an element, the list's size changes and the iteration goes of bounds. Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't delete anything; construct a new list as you walk through your data.

Comment: I am curious as to how you acquired such an... interesting data structure.

Comment: @alexis Wow, I'm not sure how that though didn't occur to me in the last hour...I must be so far down the rabbit hole that all logic has left me

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 https://blog.svpino.com/2015/05/07/five-programming-problems-every-software-engineer-should-be-able-to-solve-in-less-than-1-hour Question number 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator function that only yields values if the next value is not `C`, and accumulates otherwise:

```
def join_by(it, sep):
    it = iter(it)
    prev = next(it)
    for elem in it:
        if elem == sep:
            prev += next(it)
        else:
            yield prev
            prev = elem
    yield prev
```

Demo; this isn't limited to just digits, nor to a specific separator:

```
>>> orig = ['1', '+', '2', '+', '3', 'C', '4', 'C', '5', '-', '6', '+', '7', 'C', '8']
>>> list(join_by(orig, 'C'))
['1', '+', '2', '+', '345', '-', '6', '+', '78']
>>> list(join_by(['foo', '-', 'bar', 'baz'], '-'))
['foobar', 'baz']
```

To solve the puzzle you *could* just cheat and use `eval()` here:

```
>>> import operator
>>> from itertools import product
>>> digits = '123456789'
>>> ops = (' - ', ' + ', '')
>>> for combo in product(ops, repeat=len(digits) - 1):
...     expr = zip(digits, combo + ('',))
...     expr = ''.join([c for digit_oper in expr for c in digit_oper])
...     result = eval(expr)
...     if result == 100:
...         print(expr)
... 
1 + 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 + 6 + 78 + 9
1 + 2 + 34 - 5 + 67 - 8 + 9
1 + 23 - 4 + 5 + 6 + 78 - 9
1 + 23 - 4 + 56 + 7 + 8 + 9
12 - 3 - 4 + 5 - 6 + 7 + 89
12 + 3 - 4 + 5 + 67 + 8 + 9
12 + 3 + 4 + 5 - 6 - 7 + 89
123 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 + 8 - 9
123 - 45 - 67 + 89
123 + 4 - 5 + 67 - 89
123 + 45 - 67 + 8 - 9
```

Answer (score 4):

Filter out the "C"s then group consecutive digits:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ['1', '+', '2', '+', '3', 'C', '4', 'C', '5', '-', '6', '+', '7', 'C', '8']
new_data = [''.join(g) if k else next(g) for k, g in groupby((el for el in data if el != 'C'), key=str.isdigit)]
# ['1', '+', '2', '+', '345', '-', '6', '+', '78']
```

Comment: This assumes that there is only digits to be joined.

Comment: @Martijn indeed... but according to problem #5 that the OP has posted as a comment - it appears that only digits are in use... (not quite sure where the C's are coming from though...)

Comment: Presumably they are brute-forcing the solution by trying each of `'+'`, `'-'` and `'C'` (for concatenate) in between the digits.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yup, that's exactly what I'm doing. Out of curiosity I wanted to test things out the hard, stupid way to see just how poorly it performs and then compare it to a better algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['1', '+', '2', '+', '3', 'C', '4', 'C', '5', '-', '6', '+', '7', 'C', '8']
newlist = [lst[0]]
for idx, item in enumerate(lst[1:]):
    if item == 'C':
        continue # do nothing if it's a C
    if lst[idx] == 'C':
        newlist[-1] += item # add it to the last item if it follows a C
    else:
        newlist.append(item) # add it to the list
```

Result:

```
['1', '+', '2', '+', '345', '-', '6', '+', '78']
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for any given list and values.

```
old_list = ['1', '+', '2', '+', '3', 'C', '4', 'C', '5', '-', '6', '+', '7', 'C', '8']
new_list = []
for index, val in enumerate(old_list):
    if val == 'C':
        new_list[-1] += old_list[index+1]
    elif old_list[index-1] != 'C':
        new_list.append(val)
```

Comment: Where does `x` come from?

Comment: `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Comment: Wanted to make code more readable and forgot to change `x` into `val` :)

Answer (score 0):

No need for list comprehension, just find your delimiters and concatenate the rest

```
a = ['1', '+', '2', '+', '3', 'C', '4', 'C', '5', '-', '6', '+', '7', 'C', '8']
firstIndex = a.index('C')
revertedLastIndex = a[::-1].index('C') # index in reverted list 
lastIndex = len(a) - 1 - revertedLastIndex  # -1 for 0-indexed lists
```

So we can now just join the part of list between `firstIndex` and `lastIndex` and just concatenate the rest

```
newList = a[:firstIndex] + ["".join(a[firstIndex:lastIndex])] + a[lastIndex:]
```

Edit: By "no need for list comprehension" I mean of course no need for *explicit* iteration, the `index` function does it internally

Comment: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

Comment: Details ! =p 
Convert the string into a list first. Editing answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast

L=['1', '+', '2', '+', '3', 'C', '4', 'C', '5', '-', '6', '+', '7', 'C', '8']

s=str(L).replace(", 'C', ", "")

out=ast.literal_eval(s)

print out
```

Output:

```
['1', '+', '2', '+', '345', '-', '6', '+', '78']
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's fancy features are nice when they make the logic of the code really, really easy to follow. When they don't, I prefer to keep it simple and verifiable:

```
stuff = ['1', '+', '2', '+', '3', 'C', '4', 'C', '5', '-', '6', '+', '7', 'C', '8']
concat = False
newstuff = []
for a in stuff:
    if concat:
        newstuff[-1] += a
        concat = False
    elif a == "C":
        concat = True
    else:
        newstuff.append(a)
```